# Is there an idiom that corresponds to the Hungarian expression "fall off the other side of the horse"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, phrase-requests

There's a Hungarian phrase that can be literally translated as something like "fall off the other side of the horse". (The literal implication is either that instead of falling off this side of the horse, you fell off the other side; or that in your zeal to get on the horse, you overshot the target and fell off the other side.) It means that you are at one extreme of a situation, and you want to change it so hard that you fall into the opposite extreme. Is there an equivalent of this phrase/idiom in English?

Comment: Thank you all! None of them are exact matches, but most of them are close. I will work it out. Thanks again.

Comment: We say "bend over backwards" to describe such a condition.

Comment: @Robusto, no ‒  “bend over backwards” means  “try very hard to please someone” ([1](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&q=bend+over+backwards+meaning&oq=bend+over+backwards&gs_l=hp.1.1.0l4.1064.1064.0.2384.1.1.0.0.0.0.178.178.0j1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.5DR5mjZHxCs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1357700187,d.cGE&fp=5a56163368071ca0&biw=1053&bih=579), [2](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bend+over+backwards), [3](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7049/does-bend-over-backwards-have-bad-meaning))

Comment: I'm thinking of [“You might as well bend over backwards as lean too far forward.”](http://scienceblogs.com/insolence/2009/05/23/guilty-guilty-guilty-the-mother-who-reli/).

Comment: The resulting situation is often covered by "the cure is worse than the disease", but that doesn't really cover the action itself.

Comment: Oh, and for the curious, the Hungarian phrase in question is "átesik a ló túloldalára".

Comment: Perhaps "Out of the frying pan into the fire", meaning that in avoiding one disaster you embraced another? If you've a taste for classical allusion, "Scylla and Charybdis" means much the same thing. But neither really implies running "from one extreme to the other"

Comment: Dutch has a similar expression, but with a different meaning.  "To be lifted over the horse", indicating people who think themselves to be very important.

Comment: The meaning of the original phrase is committing oneself to the other extreme. (Getting freed from one problem and ending up in a worse situation might be a consequence, but not necessarily. For that, there exists a better phrase in Hungarian: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cseberb%C5%91l_vederbe). Examples for the horse analogy: someone reads about how healthy some kind of fruit is (what he did never eat before), and starts excessively eating it, ignoring other kinds of necessary vitamin sources. Other example: someone was criticized for being too shy, so he starts behaving too aggressively.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but related: "The pendulum swung the other way" or "The pendulum swung too far" -- means that some popular trend leaning in one direction reversed so quickly that the opposite trend is now popular.

Comment: It's kind of not looking before you leap, or putting all your eggs in one basket - jumping in with both feet is a bit milder but similar in direction.

Answer (score 16):

Simply to *'go from one extreme to the other'* or *'go from one extreme to another'*.

Answer (score 14):

If that expression means that by going to the other extreme you are still in trouble, this expression might fit:

EDIT:

***"out of the frying pan and into the fire"***

per @MikeM's comment that I had the expression slightly wrong

Comment: @Dolfy - I'm glad to help - feel free to upvote this or any of the other answers if you approve. :-)

Comment: Not exactly the same. From Wikipedia: Jumping from the frying pan into the fire is an idiom with the general meaning of escaping a bad situation for a worse.>> The few nearby expressions in English ('on the horns of a dilemma', etc) reference the 'about-to-fall' stage. The expression 'between Scylla and Charybdis' does, but apparently the Latin line 'incidit in scyllam cupiens vitare charybdim' (he runs on Scylla, wishing to avoid Charybdis) had earlier become proverbial, again according to Wikipedia.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, not exactly the same as what, the OP's original example?  Sorry, but I'm not sure whom your comment is directed at.

Comment: The expression is more commonly, _out of the frying pan [and] into the fire_.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: The expression you offer, "[out of] the frying pan into the fire", means that an even worse outcome, not an equally dire one, ensues. You only claimed that your answer 'might fit', but Dolfy identified it as a 'perfect match'. It is not. Assuming that Scylla and Charybdis were equally nasty, the meaning of the Latin expression _is_ equivalent (to one of the notions put forward by the OP - not the 'overshoot' notion) - but I don't think the English translation is used nowadays.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, gotcha.  your Scylla and Charybdis confused me since the OP was citing a horse reference but you're right - "out of the frying pan and into the fire" is going from bad to worse, not opposite but equally bad as the OP's expression implies.

Comment: I've found a reference mentioning the English translation from the Latin, Kristina, so I've posted it. Though I've never heard it in that form, and I'm not sure how common it is.

Comment: I agree. Let's popularise 'He fell off the other side of his horse' - it's a fun image. Thelwellian.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I'd rather repopularize Scylla and Charybdis - it has a certain *je ne se qua* that any horse analogy lacks. ;-)

Comment: This phrase does not capture the main meaning: that of the opposite extreme. "out of the frying pan and into the fire" has a near exact Hungarian version, with two synonyms for "bucket", and one falling from one into the other, meaning that you try to avoid a bad situation but you end up in the same one (or a worse one, but *still of the same type*). The horse analogy is used for ending up in the opposite extreme, for example when a law is considered to be discriminating against a group, they try to correct it, and end up with one that is even more discriminatory, but against the other group.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: the problem is not with equally nasty or more nasty. The problem is, just like with the Scylla and Charybdis, that it is about the same type of problem. You try to avoid a bad situation, but end up in the same (or worse), but still in the same type of a problem. This is not even close to the meaning of the horse analogy, where you end up with a completely different problem, as the result of overcompensating. And, the horse analogy does not necessarily mean a problem or a bad situation. It might only mean that you stated an opinion that is considered to be the opposite extreme.

Comment: @vsz: (1) Yes, 'the problem' was between using equally nasty and more nasty. Some contributors were failing to distinguish between the two. Falling off one side of a horse sounds just as painful as falling off the other to me; I can't see any pointer towards a worse situation. The fire is accepted to be worse than the frying pan. (2) Analogies can be interpreted to mean just about anything you wish; contributors have taken cues from the OP, some addressing the 'trying so hard to avoid one problem you blunder into another very similar problem' sense he offers as one alternative.

Comment: The other explanation for the metaphor suggested by the OP, actively adopting a policy to address a problem which sadly leads to a diametrically opposite problem, is termed hypercorrection. The difference in interpretation depends on whether one highlights the similarity in hitting the ground on either side of the horse, or the distinction between left side and right side. Without a clearer explanation of the original Hungarian usage, the question is impossible to answer in a way guaranteed to be accurate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: as a native speaker, I can tell when I usually hear this horse analogy. First when it's about "actively adopting a policy to address a problem which sadly leads to a diametrically opposite problem" what you said. The other circumstances are when in a discussion or argument someone wildly exaggerates a viewpoint, or suggests a counterargument or idea which is either dramatically opposite or dramatically exaggerated. Of course, the later one might cover "incorrect" uses. I'll search for it in linguistic books when I have the possibility and expand this comment.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : I did a search for the most common uses of the term, and its usage as "switch from one extreme to the next" is the most common one. It's not necessarily about being in a dire situation. Examples: someone reads about how healthy some kind of fruit is (what he did never eat before), and starts excessively eating it, ignoring other kinds of necessary vitamin sources. Or someone was criticized for being too impolite, and tries to overcompensate by behaving excessively politely to the point it feels unnatural. Or was criticized for being avaricious, so he starts spending a lot.

Comment: So, I'm sorry to say that it's definitely the wrong answer. The expression accentuates committing oneself to the other extreme. The point is not in "falling" but in "the other side". See http://www.youblisher.com/p/464781-O-Nagy-Gabor-Szolasok-es-koezmondasok-koenyve/ , the most exhaustive collection of Hungarian phrases. See http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cseber and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cseberb%C5%91l_vederbe  for what is the equivalent of this answer.

Comment: There's no room for interpretation-- the OP wrote that the expression at issue "means that you are **at one extreme of a situation**, and you want to change it so hard that you fall **into the opposite extreme**."

Comment: Another native speaker here, basically reinforcing what @vsz said. This answer above better fits the "bucket thing" vsz mentioned ("csöbörből vödörbe"). However, the gist of the "horse thing" is: *overcompensating* (as he also correctly noted). No translation that lacks this element captures the original intent.

Comment: And I think I'm teaming up with @EdwinAshworth in his call for popularizing the original image: "fell off the other side of the horse". I agree it's a fun way to put it! (And since we've imported a few nice ones from English to Hungarian, it's only natural to give some back. ;) )

Answer (score 10):

The idiom *[go overboard](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Going+Overboard)* (“To go to extremes, especially as a result of enthusiasm”) implies extremity, although not necessarily the *opposite* extremity.

Comment: Yes, something like that. Just found this:

Go from one extreme to the other. Maybe this is the best I can get.

Comment: Right, this is probably the closest you can get. "Going too far" may work, too. 
I miss the beauty of the Hungarian expression, though. It's a shame there's no real match in English.

Answer (score 2):

Answering the ‘It means that you are at one extreme of a situation, and you want to change it so hard that you fall into the opposite extreme’ part:

In *Old Tales Retold from Grecian Mythology in Talks Around the Fire* (1876) by Augusta Larned (as at [google books](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SHepeivyE3IC&pg=PA453&lpg=PA453&dq=%22fall+on+Charybdis%22+Scylla&source=bl&ots=ZQtZaVXO--&sig=8w_3B3WTuSH2LF2Bdyse-ogETHI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=MSnvUIeEMKGb0QX4voC4BQ&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22fall%20on%20Charybdis%22%20Scylla&f=false)), it is stated that

> *To escape Scylla only to fall on Charybdis*

‘has become a proverbial expression’.

Comment: I'm not sure how common that expression is.  In casual conversation, I suspect most people would respond with "huh?".

Comment: The problem is that it's not about an opposite extreme, but about ending up with the exact same (or maybe worse, but still of the same type) problem.

Comment: I agree with vsz-- sort of an out-of-the-frying-pan-into-the-fire feeling to it.

Comment: The tale of Scylla and Charybdis is usually used to depict a _choice_ between two evils, rather than over-enthusiasm.

Comment: [The idiom has a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis) with a lot of references.

Answer (score 2):

Though it doesn’t have the same flavor as the original Hungarian phrase, the term *overcorrect* is often used in such situations.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across an old British proverb that refers to the very situation that your Hungarian saying does. From James Kelly, [*Complete Collection of Scottish Proverbs*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BEgOAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA1&source=gbs_selected_pages&hl=en#v=onepage&q=%22Lady%20Mary%22&f=false) (1721):

> [The proverb:] *You breed of Lady Mary, when you're good you're o'er good.*
>
> [Explanation:] A drunken Man beg'd Lady *Mary* [the Virgin Mary, presumably] to help him on his Horse, and having made many Attempts to no purpose, he always reiterated the same Petition ; at length he jump'd quite over. *O Lady* Mary, (said he) *when thou art good, thou art o'er good.*

Unfortunately, as awareness of the difficulty of mounting a horse while drunk (or otherwise incapacitated) became less commonplace in the English-speaking world, this particular proverb fell into disuse. But it vividly captures the idea of finally succeeding in a difficult climb, only to go sliding down the other side (of the horse).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but [throw out the baby with the bath water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throw_out_the_baby_with_the_bath_water) might be suitable in many contexts.

Comment: No.  I'm not downvoting, but that idiom means waste by losing something valuable, in the course of getting rid of something that is undesirable.

Comment: that is a specific example of going to far though

Comment: We've got the exact same saying in Hungarian, too. However, it's not a good match for "átesni a ló túloldalára."
"Going overboard" is the closest I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

In Persian, the equivalent of this idiom is **"be careful not to fall off the other side of the roof"** and this is said of someone who is afraid of falling off in this side of the roof and so he backs up so much that he falls off the other side. Of course, you must notice that the roofs in Iran are flat. The idiom is used for someone who backtracks from one extreme to the opposite extreme.

Comment: I think the OP was after an English equivalent rather than a Persian one.

Answer (score -1):

"complete" + (U-turn, about-face, change of course, change of heart, reversal, switch in positions, turn-around, flip-flop); going to the opposite extreme

Comment: I'm surprised that two people down-voted my answer.  I wrote my answer prior to MikeM's popular answer, and mine is the most complete and correct of any here.  Answers missing key points of the requirement get lots of upvotes... insane!

Comment: For the record, i upvoted your answer because there *is* room for interpretation if you are open-minded enough to mull on another's viewpoint - **for example:**  if you were sitting in a frying pan, your butt would get hot so you would jump up - opposite of the location of the heat - but jumping up could likely have you end up in the fire, when you land.  So you might intend to go to the extreme without intending to end up somewhere worse.  That's *my* interpretation of my answer which jives with OP's intent and affirmation.

Answer (score -4):

It's not exactly a proverbial phrase, but "falling over yourself" is sometimes used for getting into some difficulty through an excess of enthusiasm:

> He was *falling over himself* to help out.

Comment: This really doesn't mean anything like the phrase in question.

Answer (score -4):

" He went at it like a bull at a gate "?

Comment: Hello, Pyramus. Though this is connected, it does not give the 'ended up in a different mess' asked for by OP.

Comment: Please give an explanation as to why this suits the request.